# Where can I find Delphi Word.Application OLE interface manual?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ole-automation

All I could find is [a simple example](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/OleAuto_CreateOleObject.html#53656520416C736F) and [a manual in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178859%28v=office.12%29.aspx) which is not the same objects as Delphi.

Edit: So there is no manual. Where could I find the code that translates the Delphi code to access the OLE calls?
In the current state, there is a guessing game with the Delphi as , how vb is translated to the Delhpi.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Where could I find the code that translate the delphi code to access the ole calls?"

Comment: step 1: you write the code which uses the OLE. step 2 : MAGIC. step 3: you compile and run the code and everything works. in step two there are other classes that allow the compiler to translate the ole call to actual call of objects. like "WordApp.Selection.TypeText('Hello World!');" there is a call to selection object and typetext object. how does delphi translate selection to the proper object as if it was called from vb?

Comment: No guessing game. You just write code against the documented COM interface. If you use early bound COM then you get compile time checking which is a huge benefit.

Comment: where can i find the com interface?

Comment: When you install Delphi you get the option of installing the Office Automation interfaces. These are just pre-prepared type library imports. I'm not with Delphi right now and can't remember where it is installed. You are looking for `TWordApplication`. It's probably defined in a file called Word2000.pas, or similar. It's in a folder called Servers or Ocx in the Delphi installation directory. Somebody please help me out here!!

Comment: @David No need for help, you got it right: on my system RAD Studio\6.0\OCX\Servers\Word2000.pas contains `TWordApplication`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The authoritative source is the [Word Object Model Reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837519.aspx). There is nothing better. It's not written using Delphi syntax but you just have to live with that.

Comment: I also don't quite agree with the closure and deletion of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304515/how-to-add-tfileattribute-switch-to-ioutils-functions). If you want, you can raise the issue on Meta.

Comment: @NullUserException Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: for : "defined in a file called Word2000.pas"

Answer (score 7):

I doubt which exist such manual, the official source is the [`Microsoft Word Object Model Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515%28v=office.12%29.aspx), The samples are in VB but you can easily translate to delphi. All these objects and properties are accesible via delphi or any language which supports COM.

Answer (score 7):

Deborah Pate's website may be "old" (~ Delphi 5) but still has valuable advice and examples in Delphi: http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/Automation.htm

Answer (score 1):

Charlie Calvert's articles on the Embarcadero Developers Network are very good as well. The articles are not linked to each other, so all url's are shown below:

Delphi 3 - Delphi and Microsoft Office: Automating Excel and Word
by Charlie Calvert, pages 1 - 5:

- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10126
- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10127
- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10128
- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10129
- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10130

Delphi and Word Part II by Charlie Calvert, pages 1 - 3

- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10043
- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10382
- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10383